# Where do I find following uid (WPD)?

Tags: c, bluetooth-lowenergy, drivers, wpd

Are following uid generated randomly or I need to find it from somewhere and if so from where?
From header stdafx.h

```
// This method submits a ReadMeasurement request. 
// {0b6b15e1-1ec4-4dde-881a-cfc3e0a7a5c7} 
DEFINE_DEVSVCGUID(METHOD_ReadHeartRateMeasurement, 0x0b6b15e1,0x1ec4,0x4dde, 0x88, 0x1a, 0xcf, 0xc3, 0xe0, 0xa7, 0xa5, 0xc7);
```

Source (WpdHealthHeartRate):
http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowshardware/Windows-Driver-Kit-WDK-80-e3161626

Answer (score 0):

My best guess that you can use Bluetooth SIG website as a reference, see [Gatt Specifications](https://developer.bluetooth.org/gatt/Pages/default.aspx) page.